# Inconsistent connection to SQL Server 2008 while debugging in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, database-connection

I'm having a ton of trouble making a consistent connection to SQL Server while debugging, lately.  We're spending most of our time diagnosing the issue from a server/networking level, but I wondered if there is a common configuration issue that might be at work here.

Here is some general information about the problem.  Frankly, I don't even know what information would be relevant.  So, any questions welcome.

- This is a web forms project using LINQ-to-SQL for data access
- It's a template that is used to create many different sites using a config setting
- Most of the data retrieval calls are made with ObjectTrackingEnabled = false
- The SQL Server is mirrored, so the connection string has a fail over
  partner specified, a connection timeout of 30 seconds, and a Network=dbmssocn
- The problem is inconsistent - but frequent - and
  only affects the site when debugging locally.
- In production, the sites log errors to the DB unless a connection fails in which case they send an email; we have received no dropped connection emails from the prod sites
- We have not experienced any large bump in traffic in terms of queries running against the SQL Server

**UPDATE**: After writing the question, I suspected that perhaps the mirrored server setup and time out was causing the issue.  Only, after setting up the connection string so that a different one is used depending on whether the site is being run in debug mode or not, I am still having the same trouble connecting.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a bad NIC.